# django cms - /url/ is becoming /en/url/, i dont know why

Tags: python, django, url, django-cms

i have installed django cms well and working also well, but now the normal urls `/url/` are becoming `/en/url/` is it normal?, i dont think that it is, because all my SEO works depend on normal url and not on `/en/url/`. can someone help me with this,

this is my settings.py: http://pastebin.com/j7crx54J

this is my urls.py: http://pastebin.com/s0QgY022

i will appreciate any help! thanks a lot

Comment: What's your cms.urls? It's important.

Comment: i solved the problem, i think what in cms.urls is , is not important since i didnot change anything inside it as shown in the docs..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try [removing](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/django-cms/1sfjcOl130Y) the [`Multilingual URL Middleware`](http://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/2.1.3/advanced/i18n.html#multilingual-url-middleware)?

Comment: hey arie, this solved my problem, thank you a lot. it doesnot have other side effects right?

Answer (score 1):

the setting `LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'` does it have to be 'en-us' ?

Answer (score 1):

Came across this question when having the exact same problem today. For me I already did not have multilingual middleware so was pretty stumped. In the process of uploading my settings files to open a question I noticed this line in the **urls.py** file:

```
urlpatterns = i18n_patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),
)
```

Well the `i18n_patterns` bit, changed that to `patterns` and the problem was solved.

### A. django-cms urls.py in tutorial

For reference here's the urls.py that the django-cms tutorial gives you (http://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting_started/tutorial.html):

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = i18n_patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),
)

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
        {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}),
    url(r'', include('django.contrib.staticfiles.urls')),
) + urlpatterns
```

This needs changing to:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = i18n_patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),
)

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
        {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}),
    url(r'', include('django.contrib.staticfiles.urls')),
) + urlpatterns
```

### B. Versions

I'm using Django 1.5.1 and django-cms 2.4.2, both the latest stable at time of writing

Answer (score 0):

You are looking in urls.py, but you should look in cms/urls.py this line in your urls.py includes it:

url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),

If you cannot find your answer in there, please post the content of this file as well.

Comment: well, in the doc, ``cms.urls`` is not supposed to be changed, so i didnot do anything in cms.urls, i just added the line into my urls.py. so i dont think, something inside of cms.url is causing the problem.. anyway, i solved it, see below @aire